# Not able to fill combo box dynamically in c#.net

Tags: c#, winforms

i am writing the below code to get the data in the combo box but it does not show any data in the combo box so please help..... below is my code for filling combo box..

```
string qry = "select ctid,city from city order by city";
cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
ds.Clear();
ad = new SqlDataAdapter(qry,con);
ad.Fill(ds);
MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[0].Rows[1]["city"].ToString());
comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "city";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ctid";
```

in the messagebox after the ad.fill(ds) i can  see the value inside the table but it is not reflecting in the combo box...

Comment: what type of application is this?

Comment: C#.net winform application in visual studio 2010

Comment: column Name and Table Name both are same right??

Comment: Yes they are right

Comment: yes the are same do they make any diffrence?

Comment: comboBox1.ValueMember = "ctid";  after this which statment you write in the your code ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the same logic in my app just the difference was to specify the CommandType property as 'Text' and CommandText property as the query, in  SqlCommand.

```
 var sqlDs = new DataSet();
 var sqlComm = new SqlCommand();
        sqlComm.Connection = sqlCon;
        sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlComm.CommandText = query;
        sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlComm);
        sqlDa.Fill(sqlDs);
```

Also when you are specifying the display member and Value member then no need to specify the columns in select query, it still work. only for the performance basis you can specify the columns name.